# Can't play sound in Ubuntu 8.04 in lenovo 3000 N200 laptop

Tags: ubuntu, audio, lenovo-laptop

Can't play sound in Ubuntu 8 in lenovo 3000 N200 laptop.

I've tried various tricks in online forums and Q&A sites but didn't help.

Please help

Comment: What exactly did you try?  Knowing what didn't work would paint a clearer picture of the problem for us, and help us give you better advice.

Comment: Seriously, plug your headphones into the mic jack and see if you can hear sound.

It's been known to happen before.

Comment: Are you speaking of Ubuntu 8.04 or 8.10? There is no "Ubuntu 8".

Comment: Any luck with your sound problem? Perhaps a clean install of Ubuntu 9.10 or even 9.04 would help.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to play a sound and then open the terminal and type "dmesg" you will get some of the system messages and that may help you debug the issue.

What I usually do is open a terminal and type "tail -f /var/log/syslog".

The tail command just shows the end of a file and the -f follows it live. So if you leave the terminal open and then try to play sounds you should see error messages in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I just find this on the [ubuntu french community](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/liste_portables_lenovo):

> Tout ne fonctionne pas du premier coup. La webcam fonctionne dans kopete après une mise à jour du système. Le capteur biométrique ne semble pas fonctionner. La carte graphique fonctionne impeccablement avec les pilotes libres intel. Le wifi est reconnu d'office, il fonctionne avec les pilotes proprios. Je ne sais pas si le lecteur de carte fonctionne, car non testé. Le gros problème à été le son. J'ai passé pas mal de temps (notamment à recompiler alsa). En fait, il faut simplement faire:
>
> sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-generic
>
> puis éditer:
>   /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base
>   pour rajouter à la fin:
>   options snd-hda-intel model=lenovo.
>   Et…. Ô joie ! Le son fonctionne…

Its means you have to type 
*sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-generic*

And after that edit the file **/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base** and add at the end
*options snd-hda-intel model=lenovo*

Its seems after that the sound will work.. I hope its will help you, impossible to me to make a test before..

Answer (score 0):

Probably not directly helpful but FWIW ...

I'm running Ubuntu 9.04 (and have run 8.10) on a Lenovo 3000 N200 and the sound is fine without loading any packages in this area other than the packages Ubuntu selected for itself.

Opening the volume control preferences it is defaulting to HDA Intel (Alsa mixer). Works on speaker and headphones. Even the buttons on the top right of the keyboard for volume up/down/mute work.